# What event and code in visual basic when the header in datagridview is clicked then all cell in that column will highlighted?

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

I have this datagridview that when the cells in quantity column are highlighted, the sum of that quantity is displayed by Total.Text. Now, my question is, what are the proper code and event that if I click the header "quantity", it will select all cell in that column, and it will sum and displays the total sum of that quantity in that column

This is my code then I highlighted some cells in column 4 (quantity) and it will sum and displays by Total.Text:

```
 Private Sub AllmatDataGridView_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles AllmatDataGridView.MouseUp



    Dim dblTotal As Double = 0

    Try
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In AllmatDataGridView.SelectedCells
            If cell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
                dblTotal += Double.Parse(cell.Value.ToString)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    If dblTotal <> 0 Then
        Total.Text = "Selected Total: " & dblTotal.ToString("n")
    Else
        Total.Text = ""
    End If


End Sub
```

If I click the header "quantity", I want it to select all cell in that column, and it will sum and displays the total sum of that quantity in that column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just attach to the SelectionChanged event and then sum everything that could reasonably be parsed as a decimal

```
Private Sub DataGridView1X_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridViewX.SelectionChanged
    SumLabel.Text = "" & DataGridViewX.SelectedCells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Sum(AddressOf AsDecimal)
End Sub

Shared Function AsDecimal(arg As DataGridViewCell) As Decimal
    Decimal.TryParse(arg.Value, AsDecimal)
End Function
```

Your user can flexibly select anything ; a full column, a row, a rectangle, a single cell, random cells all over the place, and any that are numeric will be added to the total

Comment: thanks for the respond. how about when header is click then all cell in that column will be selected and sum and will display by the total.text?

Comment: The code responds to a change in the selected cells of the DataGridView, no? (It doesn't matter how the change occurs)